# Count the frequency of words from a column in Python

Tags: python, csv, tabular

I have a csv file. 
The structure of the csv file is:

```
Name Hour Location
A    4    San Fransisco
B    2    New York
C    4    New York
D    7    Denton
E    8    Boston
F    1    Boston
```

If you observe the data above, There are

```
2 New York and
2 Boston
```

I tried to use the tabular package. I tried the tutorials mentioned in the tabular package documentation since more than 7 hours. But I dint get through.

Can anyone help me, how can I extract the count of the frequent words in that Csv file in the Location column using Python.

Thank you.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I tried to use the package tabular.

Comment: @robert, Yes I mentioned the count in front for 2 of New York.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
data = """Name\tHour\tLocation
A\t4\tSan Fransisco
B\t2\tNew York
C\t4\tNew York
D\t7\tDenton
E\t8\tBoston
F\t1\tBoston
"""

import csv
import StringIO
from collections import Counter


input_stream = StringIO.StringIO(data)
reader = csv.reader(input_stream, delimiter='\t')

reader.next() #skip header
cities = [row[2] for row in reader]

for (k,v) in Counter(cities).iteritems():
    print "%s appears %d times" % (k, v)
```

Output:

```
San Fransisco appears 1 times
Denton appears 1 times
New York appears 2 times
Boston appears 2 times
```

Comment: +1 Although I would have `Counter(row[2] for row in reader)` so it doesn't iterate through the cities twice and create and intermediary list.

Comment: if you are using python 2.7 and above you might want to take note that "iteritems" change to "items". Never the less, this will have the same result as iteritems.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what you are separating by but the example shows up as 4 spaces so this is a solution for that.

If you actually are separating by tabs use the answer by @MariaZverina

```
import collections

with open('test.txt') as f:
    next(f) # Skip the first line
    print collections.Counter(line.rstrip().rpartition('    ')[-1] for line in f)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'New York': 2, 'Boston': 2, 'San Fransisco': 1, 'Denton': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Even though you used a txt file instead of a csv file as I mentioned, this gives me an idea.

Comment: @user907629 Right I just copied what you had there into a `.txt`. Your file doesn't have a good structure so you might wanna go with a more conventional one like actual comma separated values. EDIT: Just realized they are tabs but they seem to have come out as spaces or at least I think so

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't too large, the most naive way would be:

- Read the file line by line
- Append the values for location to a list
- Build a set of uniques from that list
- Determine the count for each of the uniques in the list