# Count the occurrence of same words in a csv file which occurs in the same row in python

Tags: python, csv

I have an external csv file and i want to count the occurrence of same words which appears in the same row.
my csv looks like this

```
Timestamp,Destination,Source
2015-05-25,A,B
2015-05-25,A,B
2015-05-25,A,B
2015-05-25,C,D
2015-05-25,C,D
2015-05-25,E,F
2015-05-25,E,F
2015-05-25,E,F
2015-05-25,E,F
```

As in the above csv file the words A,B appears to communicate with each other 3 times C,D 2 times and E,F 4 times so i want to write this information in a csv file using python.
it should appear something like this

```
Destination,Source,Counts
A,B,3
C,D,2
E,F,4
```

Comment: Please share us what you have tried so far... There are many ways to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you can easily count occurrences of words.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('words.csv') as f:
    next(f)  # skip header
    occurrence = Counter(tuple(row[1:3]) for row in csv.reader(f))

with open('occurrence.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Destination', 'Source', 'Counts'])
    for (dest, src), cnt in occurrence.items():
        writer.writerow([dest, src, cnt])
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted sir @falsetru.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost all the logic from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463263/count-the-frequency-of-words-from-a-column-in-python-using-external-csv-file/34463573?noredirect=1#comment56683399_34463573), you just need to write the items:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from itertools import imap
from operator import  itemgetter

with open('in.csv') as f, open("out.csv", "w") as o:
    wr = csv.writer(o)
    next(f)
    o.write("Destination,Source,Counts")
    wr.writerows([a, b, c] for (a, b), c in
                 Counter(imap(itemgetter(1, 2), csv.reader(f))).iteritems())
```

out.csv:

```
Destination,Source,Counts
A,B,3
C,D,2
E,F,4
```