# Count how often specific row values occur & output the combinations in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV that contains sales data that I want to iterate through to list categories that are purchased often by the same buyer. I think I can do this with a dictionary and [a script like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463263/count-the-frequency-of-words-from-a-column-in-python-using-external-csv-file) but I am having trouble conceptualizing how to count how many times the same buyer shows up across different categories.

CSV data sample:

```
buyer_id | order_id | category
1, 10, shoes
1, 11, outerwear
2, 12, beauty
2, 13, shoes
2, 14, outerwear
```

In that sample, I would want to know that shoes, outerwear are a combination at least 2 times.

Comment: you want to know how many times each of the category is repeated in the csv right?

Comment: You are looking for market basket analysis. (Google it, read about it.)

Comment: show the desired result

Comment: @DYZ I found this example and it was everything I wanted. Thank you for the nudge! https://dzenanhamzic.com/2017/01/19/market-basket-analysis-mining-frequent-pairs-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
#Creating dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Buyer_ID': [1,1,2,2,2,1],
     'Order_ID': [10,11,12,13,14,15],
     'Category':['shoes','outerwear','beauty','shoes','outerwear','shoes']
    })

data
Out[]: 
   Buyer_ID   Category  Order_ID
0         1      shoes        10
1         1  outerwear        11
2         2     beauty        12
3         2      shoes        13
4         2  outerwear        14
5         1      shoes        15

# Output: Same buyer and unique categories
data.groupby(["Buyer_ID", "Category"]).size()

# Buyer_ID:1 with two shoes entry is displayed only once (hence only unique categories are considered). 
Out[]: 
Buyer_ID  Category 
1         outerwear    1
          shoes        2
2         beauty       1
          outerwear    1
          shoes        1
dtype: int64
```